# Why is this my attempt of spawning endless Threads stopping at 4?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I have this simple code in Java 8:

```
class ThreadTest {
    void threadTest() {
        new Thread(this::threadTest).start();
        System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest().threadTest();
    }
}
```

and I was pretty much expecting to see very large numbers getting printed.  All I see in the console is:

```
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
```

I said maybe I am not able to see others for whatever reason and modified the code as below:

```
class ThreadTest {
    void threadTest() {
        new Thread(this::threadTest).start();
        if (Thread.activeCount() > 4) {
            System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest().threadTest();
    }
}
```

and now nothing gets printed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your machine has 4 cores and there cannot be more than 4 threads running at a time, would be my guess.

Comment: When a thread ends (when the end of `threadTest()` is reached) it is removed.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I see, you are totally right. I added a Thread.sleep(50000) after the print statement and I very quickly got values like 4000 etc.. And my computer restarted.. Weird..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once your thread reaches the end of its execution (in your case, the end of the `threadTest()` method), it is no longer an active thread.

If you add an excessively long `Thread.sleep` in your method, you will see this active thread count increase further.

Comment: You just combined @MichaelButscher 's comment and my response to it? I guess it is good enough, here is a green tick from me to you.

Comment: That comment should have been posted as answer, +1 for conversion effort :)